# User Account Disabled After Upgrade to 12.04.1 LTS

Tags: 12.04

I upgraded from 10.xxx to 12.04.1 LTS using the upgrade feature within Ubuntu. System upgraded but after a reboot, the graphical interface comes up. When I try logging in using a user account that pre-existed on the system, the graphical interface screen disappears, screen goes blank and then reverts to the graphical interface prompting for a password. I have loads of data and installed programs under the particular user account. PLEASE HELP....

Answer (score 1):

Step one would be to try non-graphical login (press `ctrl-alt-1` or `ctrl-alt-2`). If you can log in there, it's not the account that's broken, but the graphical interface. You'll also be able to see any error messages that your login produces.

If you can login, then you need to find out why your graphical interface doesn't work. My suggestion would be to create a new user (see for instace http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/add-a-user-on-ubuntu-server/ ) and log in with that. It might be some script you ran on your old installation.

Comment: I tried as suggested. Thank you. I can log in using the terminal window no problem. Now to fix the login via graphical interface to enable me to access installed programs. Any suggestions? Thanks for your input /Five

Comment: I would add a new user like I posted, and try to log in with that user. if that works, there is something wrong with your account (.setting files in your home dir?). If that doesn't work there is something wrong with your graphical installation.

Comment: Thank you. Can log in via the graphical interface using a new user that was created. Will browse the help to establish how to sort out the original user's graphical interface